# yes/no program not working properly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following code that I wrote myself:

```
mov ah, 9h
mov dx, offset cool
int 21h

mov ah, 1h
int 21h

cmp al, 79 
je _yes
jne _no

_yes:
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset yes
    int 21h 

_no:
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset no
    int 21h


mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

cool db "Are you cool [y/n]: $"
yes db 0ah, 0dh, "Yay, me too!$" 
no db 0ah, 0dh, "LOL, you'r a loser!$"
```

Everything works perfectly, except for when I press the `y` key. If I press any key except for `y`, it displays "LOL, you're a loser", which is exactly what I want it to do. But when I press the `y` key, it displays "Yay, me too!", which is correct, but it also displays "LOL you're a loser". What is meant to happen is, if you press the `y` key, it display "Yay, me too" and when you press any key besides `y`, it is only meant to display "LOL, you're a loser!" 
If I did not explain well enough, please comment an I will try and explain it better.
Thanks in advance :)
PS I am using x86 assembly, as you probably can see

Comment: You should use the debugger to figure out why.

Comment: why do you expect that after pressing "y", and the "yes"-message is printed, the "no"-message would not be printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_no` part is located directly after the `_yes` part in your code. A label is just a convenient name for a location in your program - it's not some sort of barrier. So the CPU has no idea that you only want one of those to be executed and will just keep on executing whatever instructions it finds.

Add a jump if you want to skip over code. For example:

```
_yes:
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset yes
    int 21h 
    jmp done  ; jump to done so that the "no" message isn't printed

_no:
....

done:
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
```